# Apt-Dater: Error executing Error executing 'lsb_release -a'

Tags: centos, debian, yum, apt, update

I successfully deployed apt-dater (Debian-machine) and apt-dater-host (CentOS) to 2 different nodes via puppet.

Now apt-dater is showing the new host, but the state is always "unknown".

If I enter diag-screen, I'm getting this result:

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
ADPROTO: 0.6

ADPERR: Error executing 'lsb_release -a' (32512).
```

Any idea what to do?

Comment: Do you try to run the 'lsb_release -a' on the host ? It is maybe missing.

Comment: Mea culpa. That solved it!

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to run the 'lsb_release -a' on the host ? It is maybe missing.